# iphone:how to set table background Image

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I tried that as 1st took image view as background of table view and select the image.then i perform the following code in view will appear:

```
  table.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

and also clear the custom cell label.but it overlaps the table values.

Comment: You may actually want to put the image view behind the table view.

Comment: please be clarify your problem bcoz i can't understand what you say

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me

```
UIImageView *tempImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
[tempImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0071.JPG"]];
[testTableView setBackgroundView:tempImg];
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use transparent UITableView on the UIImageView. Put your image into the image view and it looks like table's background image as you want

Answer (score 1):

you might wanna try putting UIImage behind UITableView.. Use method `insertView:atIndex:` on a view.

also.. you might wanna look at this tutorial by Matt Gallagher
http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear tableviewcell background color. You have to write this code before `return cell;` statement.

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

And also table cell label color.